# How to find the tangent plane to a surface when the function is given implicitly?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have the function $yze^{xz} - 8 = 0$ and need to find its tangent plane at the point $(x_{0}, y_{0}, z_{0})$. Now I know how to do this if the function is in the form $z = f(x, y)$ but I can't put this function in this form due to the exponential. How should I proceed?

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the tangent plane is given by $a (x - x_0) + b(y - y_0) + c(z - z_0) = 0$, where

$(a,b,c) = \nabla f(x,y,z)\mid_{(x_0,y_0,z_0)} = (y_0z_0^2e^{x_0y_0}, z_0e^{x_0,z_0}, x_0y_0z_0e^{x_0z_0} + y_0e^{x_0z_0})$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for a graph of the form
$$
g(x,y,z) = 0
$$
The gradient $\nabla g(x,y,z) = (g_x(x,y,z),g_y(x,y,z),g_z(x,y,z))$ gives a vector that is normal (i.e. perpendicular) to the surface of the graph. The equation of the plane at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ is thus
$$
g_x(x_0,y_0,z_0)(x-x_0) + g_y(x_0,y_0,z_0)(y-y_0) + g_z(x_0,y_0,z_0)(z-z_0) = 0
$$